# Is it possible store static array of objects for separate instances in game in pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, static

I have the class `StdObject`. My goal is to have this as a **superclass** and store objects for each instance of the classes that inherit from this StdObject-class instead of storing arrays for each object. It seemed to make more sense to store call `getAll()` as a static method.

```
class StdObject {
    static objs = [];

    //When creating new objects, these properties 
    //are used/set by default
    constructor(x=null,y=0,width=10,height=10,speed=0.4) {                   
        if (x == null) x = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas_width);
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.speed = speed;
        this.friction = 0.3;    
        this.color = '#000000'; 
        this.gravity = 0;    
        this.constructor.addObj(); //Add this instance to the array
    }

    //Update is here if no update() is created in classes
    //the extends this class
    update() {};
        
    //Render the objects to the canvas as rectangle
    //If another shape should be used, just create a render() in that class
    //to overwrite this method
    render() {      
        ctx.clearRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);  
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);       
    }

    //Adds an object to objects array objs
    static addObj() {
        this.objs.push(this);
    }

    //Gets a specific object in array objs
    static getObj(index) {
        return this.objs[index];
    }

    //Get all objects (StdObject.getAll() is called instead of the actual class used)
    //because there are no inheritance when static methods are used.
    static getAll() {
        console.log(this);
        console.log('ALL OBJECTS=');
        console.log(this.objs);
        return this.objs;
    }

}

class Ball extends StdObject {
    constructor(x,y,width,height,speed) {
        super(x,y,width,height,speed);      
        this.angle = 0;
        this.shoot = 0;
        this.moving = false;
        this.speed = 0;
        this.radius = 7;
    }

    update() {
       //Move, update of positions for these balls etc
    }

    render() {
        //Update to canvas
    }
}

class Enemy extends StdObject {
    constructor(x,y,width,height,speed) {
        super(x,y,width,height,speed);      
        this.angle = 0;
        this.shoot = 0;
        this.moving = false;
        this.speed = 0;
    }

    update() {
       //Move, update of positions for these enemies etc
    }

    render() {
        //Update to canvas
    }
}
```

In the game-loop I would like to do something like this:

```
var obl = StdObject.getAll().length;

function gameLoop() {
    let i;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for(i=0;i<obl;i++) {
        StdObject.getObj[i].update();
    }

    for(i=0;i<obl;i++) {
        StdObject.getObj[i].render();          
    }
    
    window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
}
```

The issue is that `StdObject.getObj[i].update();` and `StdObject.getObj[i].render();` is not refered to the actual instance of the object (They are referenced to the objects inside of the static array in StdObject class). Therefore I get errors

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'update') at gameLoop*

**Is this possible to solve with static methods?** (It does not make sense to create an instance of an object just to retrieve all instances of that object.)

( Yes, I know I could store a global variable with all array of objects and just loop through them and call update() and render() )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues with the code.

1. You are trying to call a function as array but it should be called as function, StdObject.getObj(i).render() instead of StdObject.getObj[i].render();
2. When creating instance in constructor it was not getting registered properly in array objs.

```js
class StdObject {
            static objs = [];
            //When creating new objects, these properties 
            //are used/set by default
            constructor(x=null,y=0,width=10,height=10,speed=0.4) {                   
                if (x == null) x = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas_width);
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
                this.width = width;
                this.height = height;
                this.speed = speed;
                this.friction = 0.3;    
                this.color = '#000000'; 
                this.gravity = 0;    
                StdObject.addObj(this); //Add this instance to the array
            }
        
            //Update is here if no update() is created in classes
            //the extends this class
            update() {};
                
            //Render the objects to the canvas as rectangle
            //If another shape should be used, just create a render() in that class
            //to overwrite this method
            render() {      
                ctx.clearRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);  
                ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
                ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);       
            }
        
            //Adds an object to objects array objs
            static addObj(obj) 
            {
                StdObject.objs.push(obj);
            }
        
            //Gets a specific object in array objs
            static getObj(index) {
                return this.objs[index];
            }
        
            //Get all objects (StdObject.getAll() is called instead of the actual class used)
            //because there are no inheritance when static methods are used.
            static getAll() {
                console.log(this);
                console.log('ALL OBJECTS=');
                console.log(this.objs);
        
                return this.objs;
            }
        
        }
        
        class Ball extends StdObject {
            constructor(x,y,width,height,speed) {
                super(x,y,width,height,speed);      
                this.angle = 0;
                this.shoot = 0;
                this.moving = false;
                this.speed = 0;
                this.radius = 7;
            }
        
            update() {
               //Move, update of positions for these balls etc
                console.log('Ball update');
            }
        
            render() {
                //Update to canvas
                console.log('Ball render');
            }
        }
        
        class Enemy extends StdObject {
            constructor(x,y,width,height,speed) {
                super(x,y,width,height,speed);      
                this.angle = 0;
                this.shoot = 0;
                this.moving = false;
                this.speed = 0;
            }
        
            update() {
               //Move, update of positions for these enemies etc
            console.log('update enemy');
            }
        
            render() {
                //Update to canvas
                console.log('render enemy');
            }
        }
        
        
        
        var enemy = new Enemy(100,100,10,10,0.4);
        var ball = new Ball(100,100,10,10,0.4);
        
        const ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
        
        function gameLoop() 
        {
        var obl = StdObject.getAll().length;
        
            let i;
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            for(i=0;i<obl;i++) {
                StdObject.getObj(i).update();
            }
        
            for(i=0;i<obl;i++) {
                StdObject.getObj(i).render();          
            }
            
            window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
        }
        
        gameLoop();
```

Comment: The method/array issue was a mistake. Thank you. 

When I do like you proposed I get this error:

Uncaught TypeError: StdObject.getObj(...).update is not a function
    at gameLoop

Comment: Did you also update the addObj function? its definition and its constructor call in StdObject class as per my code?

Comment: aha.. I copied all the code you hade for StdObject and it works now!! Thank you very much!